# .NET Excel kernel32.dll error while renaming the sheet name

Tags: .net, runtime-error, office-interop

I have an application. In this application, I connect to the reporting service, render a report and export it in Excel(xls).

I create a Process() object and run an .exe like below;

```
Process excelRename = new Process();
excelRename.StartInfo.FileName = "the path of the .exe";
excelRename.StartInfo.Arguments = (string)parameters["targetfile"] + " " +commandArgument;
excelRename.Start();
excelRename.WaitForExit();
```

This works on my machine( Win7, Office 2010).
But not working on the server ( Win Server 2003 SP2, Office 2007 )

The last modified date of the .exe on the server is in 2012. I don't know the specifications of the server at that time( I mean if it was Office 2003 or Win Server SP1 or anything else ).

When I run the application on my computer, it can render the report, start that Process and change the sheet names of the excel output successfully.

But when I copy the .exe file to the server, I get the error below;

- .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting -->
  Faulting application renameexcelsheetnametahsilatraporu.exe, version 1.0.0.0, stamp 52df8987, **faulting module kernel32.dll**, version 5.2.3790.5069, stamp 506be89c, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.

**I've been searching for it for hours , but couldn't find any solution. Is there anybody to help me?**

Comment: Maybe that file is still locked by another proces? use [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to diagnose.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: I render a report, it comes in .xls format and there are 15 sheets within it. The program changes the sheet names. I can get the output excel with Process class. After this, i get an error like i mentioned.